# Way to select certain row values based on values of another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried searching for this but get a lot of filters on entire tables. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.2100.60.

My query currently returns something like this below.

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦════════════════╦═══════╦════════════╗
║  Account  ║ Balance ║    Invoice     ║ Code  ║    Date    ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬════════════════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 500018802 ║ -80.00  ║ 500018802-0002 ║ PBH   ║ 2012-04-05 ║
║ 500018802 ║ -140.00 ║ 500018802-0003 ║ DLPBH ║ 2012-05-05 ║
║ 500018802 ║ -60.00  ║ 500018802-0006 ║ DLPBH ║ 2012-08-05 ║
║ 500018802 ║ -140.00 ║ 500018802-0001 ║ PBH   ║ 2012-03-23 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩════════════════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

What I'm trying to do is group the data to get one Account number while summing the Balance. However, I can't do a simple group because the Invoice/Code/Dates are different. So is there a way to select certain row values to be something depending on other column values? What I want ideally is to take the Code and Date values to be whatever they are in the row where the Invoice Number has the minimum value while summing the balance. So in this case, it's the last row and my result would be:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦════════════════╦══════╦════════════╗
║  Account  ║ Balance ║    Invoice     ║ Code ║    Date    ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬════════════════╬══════╬════════════╣
║ 500018802 ║ -420.00 ║ 500018802-0001 ║ PBH  ║ 2012-03-23 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩════════════════╩══════╩════════════╝
```

This is just data for ONE Account. My table would have many rows of many accounts.

EDIT* This is my current query.

```
SELECT Account
    SUM(Balance) AS Balance,
    Invoice,
    Code,
    Date
FROM MyData
GROUP BY Account,   Invoice, Code, Date
ORDER BY Account
```

Comment: thank you SO much to Politank-Z for the table edit! I tried looking into inserting clean tables but having trouble finding the answer!

Comment: You can either put 4 spaces at the beginning of each line, or highlight the effected text and click the `{}` button on the text editor. In the latter case, control-k also works, but that is also a hot key in some browsers.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried it in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT 
        Account,
        SUM(Balance) OVER (PARTITION BY Account) Balance,
        Invoice,
        Code,
        [Date],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY Invoice) RN
    FROM
        Accounts
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example:

```
with cte1 as(your current query),
cte2 as(select *, 
               row_number() over(partition by account order by invoice) rn,
               sum(balance) over(partition by account) as b
        from cte1)
select * from cte2
where rn = 1
```